# Swift allSatisfy allow 'Enter' or New Line

Tags: swift

I have the following extension.

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func isLetterDigit(allowChars: String) -> Bool {
        allSatisfy("\(allowChars)".contains)
    }
}
```

I am using it like so:

```
if (!bioTextView.text!.isLetterDigit(allowChars: self.allowChars)) {
    displaySnackbar(messageString: "Remove special characters in your bio")
}
```

`bioTextView` is a UITextView where I will allow users to use the enter key is they wish.

My allowChars is the following

```
var allowChars: String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .',!:"
```

How can I allow the enter key/new line?

Comment: Not related to your question but it is better to use a set of characters instead of a string

Comment: Instead of showing an alert why don't you simply filter only the allowed characters ?

Answer (score 1):

The character for newline is `\n`. I expect you'll also want `\"` at some point to allow double-quotes. The leading backslash is the "escape" character in Swift strings to characters to mark special characters. See ["Special Characters in String Literals"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID286)  for the full list.

You don't need to string-interpolate `allowChars`, however:

```
allSatisfy(allowChars.contains)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### *A* simple way

As pointed out by @LeoDabus you can also quite simple use a set of `Character` :

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func isLetterDigit(allowedChars: Set<Character>) -> Bool {
        allowedChars.isSuperset(of: self)
    }
    func isLetterDigit() -> Bool {
        allSatisfy { $0.isLetter || $0.isWhitespace || $0.isNewline || $0.isNumber || $0.isPunctuation }
    }
}
"?".isLetterDigit(allowedChars: allowedCharacters) // false
"Hello World!".isLetterDigit(allowedChars: allowedCharacters) // true
"?".isLetterDigit() // true
"Hello World!".isLetterDigit() // true
```

#### Using [`CharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset):

You can also use `CharacterSet` directly :

```
var allowedChars: CharacterSet = .init("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .',!:".unicodeScalars)
allowedChars.isSuperset(of: .init("Hello World!".unicodeScalars)) // true
allowedChars.isSuperset(of: .init("?".unicodeScalars)) // false
```

but you can use the standard character sets eg. :

```
var standardAllowedChars: CharacterSet = .whitespacesAndNewlines
standardAllowedChars.formUnion(.alphanumerics)
standardAllowedChars.formUnion(.punctuationCharacters)
standardAllowedChars.isSuperset(of: .init("Hello World!".unicodeScalars)) // true
standardAllowedChars.isSuperset(of: .init("?".unicodeScalars)) // true
```

and finally your extension can also use `CharacterSet` eg. :

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func isLetterDigit(allowChars: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        allowChars.isSuperset(of: .init(unicodeScalars))
    }
}
"?".isLetterDigit(allowChars: standardAllowedChars) // true 
"?".isLetterDigit(allowChars: allowedChars) // false
```

And to answer your question about new lines, [`CharacterSet.whitespaces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779930-whitespaces), [`CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779801-whitespacesandnewlines) and [`CharacterSet.newlines`](http://%60CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines%60)
will probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: Just use a set of characters instead of a CharacterSet

Comment: IMO it is much cleaner. You can simply pass a string `allowedChars.isSuperset(of: "Hello World!")`

Comment: I just edited, I like the idea of using standard character set though

Comment: why not simply `allowedChars.isSuperset(of: self)`

Comment: check the method signature `func isSuperset<S>(of possibleSubset: S) -> Bool where Character == S.Element, S : Sequence`

Comment: no neet to use `.init()` at all.  `StringProtocol` conforms to `Sequence` and its `Element` is a `Character`

Comment: yeah I don't know why I thought I needed a substring

Comment: I think it's clean now, thanks for the review ;)

Comment: Note that character property  `isNumber` will allow fractions as well which is not included on OP's allowed characters. Another point is `isLetter` which will allow all sort of letters which might not be what OP wants.

Comment: yes, and `punctuation` allows `?` which is not in OP question. but I this was offered as a standard alternative and for `?` at least I indicated what the result was

Comment: I think you meant to comment on OP question ;)

Comment: I agree but to me SO is about having fun with random programming problems and trying new stuff. And I don't know maybe OP was asked to do things this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Rob's answer. I think you should simply filter unwanted characters instead of showing an alert to the user. Just subclass textview, make it its delegate and implement textViewDidChange method. Then you can simply remove all characters that are not supposed to be allowed in your textview:

---

```
class TextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
    var allowChars: Set = .init(#"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .',!:\n"#)
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        delegate = self
        keyboardType = .asciiCapable
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        text.removeAll(where: allowChars.notContains)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Set {
    @inlinable public func notContains(_ member: Element) -> Bool { !contains(member) }
}
```

---

Don't forget to set your textview custom class property in your project identity inspector

[image]